# how convert io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest to CompletableFuture

Tags: java, kotlin, completable-future, micronaut, micronaut-client

I am following [4 Low Level Client](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-http-client-kotlin/guide/index.html) and I want adjust the example to return a CompletableFuture. My final goal is consume two different endpoints in parallel. I am very new in Micronaut. I believe one good approach would be created two Micronaut Low Level Clients which return a completable future and then join both with CompletableFuture.allOf().join()

So I code the service as

```
import com.mycomp.application.clients.EmployeClient
import com.mycomp.application.clients.EmployeeLowLevelClient
import java.awt.desktop.PrintFilesEvent
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class EmployeeService {

    @Inject
    lateinit var employeClient: EmployeClient //Declarative Cliente

    @Inject
    lateinit var employeeLowLevelClient: EmployeeLowLevelClient //Low Level Client

    fun thenCombineAsyncExample() {

        val allFutures: MutableList<CompletableFuture<String>> = ArrayList<CompletableFuture<String>>()

        allFutures.add(employeClient.getEmployeesA()) //### THIS WORKS
        allFutures.add(employeClient.getEmployeesB()) //### THIS WORKS
        employeeLowLevelClient.getEmployeeSurname()?.let { allFutures.add(it) } //### THIS FAILS

        CompletableFuture.allOf(*allFutures.toTypedArray<CompletableFuture<*>>()).join()

        for (i in 0..1) {
            print("response: " + allFutures[i].get().toString())
        }
    }
}
```

And the low level client as

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.client.RxHttpClient
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class EmployeeLowLevelClient(private val httpClient: RxHttpClient) {
    internal fun getEmployeeSurname(): CompletableFuture<String>? {

        val req = HttpRequest.GET<String>("http://localhost:3000/employees_a?first_name=Jimis")
        //val flowable = httpClient.retrieve(req)
        return req as CompletableFuture<String> //### HERE IS THE ISSUE

    }
}
```

The excception is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.micronaut.http.client.netty.NettyClientHttpRequest cannot be cast to class java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture (io.micronaut.http.client.netty.NettyClientHttpRequest is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Interesting I am not getting exception with Declarative Client.

```
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client
import io.reactivex.Single
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture

@Client()
interface EmployeClient {

    @Get("http://localhost:3000/employees_a?first_name=Jimis")
    fun getEmployeesA(): CompletableFuture<String>

    @Get("http://localhost:3001/employees_b?first_name=Jimis")
    fun getEmployeesB(): CompletableFuture<String>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to make some Http requests asynchronously...

The following lines are relatively straight forward but I think may be where there's some confusion...

```kotlin
val allFutures: MutableList<CompletableFuture<String>> = ArrayList<CompletableFuture<String>>()

allFutures.add(employeClient.getEmployeesA()) //### THIS WORKS
allFutures.add(employeClient.getEmployeesB()) //### THIS WORKS
employeeLowLevelClient.getEmployeeSurname()?.let { allFutures.add(it) }
```

You create a List of `CompletableFuture`s. You then add two `CompletableFuture`s to it. then you use a "client" to call `getEmployeeSurname()` with the `CompletableFuture`s.

So it looks to me like you want `getEmployeeSurname()` to return a `CompletableFuture` so you can add it to the list of `allFutures`

So you want a function for `getEmployeeSurname()` more like:

```kotlin
internal fun getEmployeeSurname(): CompletableFuture<String>? {

        val req = HttpRequest.GET<String>("http://localhost:3000/employees_a?first_name=Jimis")
        //val flowable = httpClient.retrieve(req)
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(req)
    }
```

This function then returns the Http request wrapped in a completable future. You cannot just cast from an HttpClient to a CompletableFuture as there's no commonality between the two.

So now when you do:

```kotlin
employeeLowLevelClient.getEmployeeSurname()?.let { allFutures.add(it) }
```

It should add the `CompletableFuture` calls should run on a separate thread without blocking the execution on the main thread.

Comment: Rob, thanks. I am getting "Type mismatch.
Required:
CompletableFuture<String>?
Found:
CompletableFuture<Void!>!" at "... CompletableFuture.runAsync(req)...".